# How to quietly change the System Locale in R

Tags: r

I'd like to be able to change the "LC_TIME" locale in R using (eg) `Sys.setlocale("LC_TIME", "de_DE.UTF-8")`, but I'd like to do this without returning the new locale.

One option is to use `quiet()` from the `ddpcr` package, but I'd love to know if there are other options?

Comment: `help("invisible")`? It still returns the locale name but without printing.

Comment: This works well for my purposes and is in base R which is great.  If you want to leave this as an answer I will endorse.  Thanks!